# Why are statically bound methods not involved in the CIR ( Class instance Record ) of the class while dynamically bound methods are?

Tags: java, oop, methods, object-oriented-analysis, class-instance-variables

I read in Sebesta that static bound methods do not need to be stored in the CIR but i cant figure out why. If it is not stored in the CIR, how does the compiler know which statically bound method is being referred to and where it is stored?

Comment: The compiler knows because it is compiling the program. It doesn't use the CIR. The runtime system uses the CIR. At runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A static method can’t be overridden. So at compile time the Compiler already knows which code to invoke. Instead of having to defer to runtime resolution.